# Matter implementation in IOS

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, mesh-network

I am trying to create one IOS application that can commission a Light Matter device with OTBR (open tread border router) using a thread network

What I did:
I enabled the Xcode Matter capability on the iPhone, downloaded the following profiles and installed them on the iPhone.

- EnableBluetoothCentralMatterClientDeveloperMode
- ThreadNetwork Framework Support

Even I enabled "com.apple.developer.networking.multicast" in the Apple developer account.
As of now, I am using Apple Matter API in the Matter extension target.

NOTE: I am able to start the commission device but failing in between and not able to complete a commission.

The error I am getting while commissioning:

- [THClient] Client: -[THClient connectToXPCService]_block_invoke - CTCS XPC Client is invalidated."
- [u FA78E8E5-E4F5-44B4-8087-DC48DCBAAB98] [()] host connection from pid 6381 invalidated
- [device.setup.manager] [4257EE8A-3BBD-457A-A120-19813B323910] Failed to perform Matter device setup setup: Error Domain=HMErrorDomain Code=18 "Pairing Failed" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Pairing Failed, NSUnderlyingError=0x282265a10 {Error Domain=HAPErrorDomain Code=15 "(null)"}}

If you have any idea what I am missing please help me.

Thanks.

Comment: You said what you DID.  You never said what HAPPENED.  What problems are you having?

Comment: Hi @TimRoberts I have added errors Also which I am getting